# How to get array data in url in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my Route.php

```
Route::get('users/{user_name}/{source}/{destination}/{members}' , 'Userscontroller@index');
```

I want array of members in url. How can I get it and How can I pass to `index()` in `UsersController`.

Here is my UsersController.php

```
public function index($user_name, $source , $destination , $members[] )
    {

        $users = DB::table('users')->insert(array(
            'user_name' => $user_name,
            'source' => $source,
            'destination' => $destination,
        ));
    }
```

How Can I store array of members in database as well ?

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: it's not a good practice to get array in url.

Comment: Yes. but there is a need so I want to have array in URL

Comment: Remove `members` from the route and use query strings `?members[]=member1&members[]=member2`. Then inside `index()` use [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#retrieving-input).

Comment: then you can json_encode the array and use it on the url and then get the back the data from url and decode it to array. then insert it on the database

Comment: Use a query string.

Comment: I might not have fixed number of members every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Route::get('users/{user_name}/{source}/{destination}/{members}' , 'Userscontroller@index')->where(['members'=>'.*']);
```

Then in your controller...

```
$members = explode("/", $members);
```

This would let you use a URL like

> /users/user_name/source/destination/member1/member2/member3

---

For storing arrays in databases whilst using eloquent... I've just realised you're not using a Model here but inserting straight into the database, I'd suggest creating a Users model and then you can do this with the below. Otherwise any request for this data you'll need to remember to manually unserialise in whatever format you serialised the data in.

Using attribute casting inside a model (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting):

Add to the Model:

```
protected $casts = ['members'=>'array'];
```

Then you let Laravel do the rest for you:

```
 $users = Users::insert(array(
        'user_name' => $user_name,
        'source' => $source,
        'destination' => $destination,
        'members' => $members
    ));
```

Comment: I might have different number of members. So will it work?

Comment: The route and controller techniques in my answer will work for any numbers of members. It'll work with 1 member or 100 members :)

Comment: Okay. Thank You. I will check and will inform for the same.